# ReferenceError: function name is not defined

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am getting `ReferenceError: imageUpdate is not defined` error
I provided my js code below:
I converted this code from coffeescript.

```
imageUpdate = function() {
  alert("called");
  return $(".image_content img").dblclick(function() {
    var current_img, img_align, img_caption, img_data, img_width;
    img_data = $(this).attr("src");
    img_width = $(this).parent(".image_content")[0].style.width;
    img_width = img_width.substring(0, img_width.length - 1);
    img_align = $(this).parent(".image_content").attr("data-align");
    img_caption = $(this).siblings(".caption").text();
    current_img = $(this);
    return $.ajax({
      url: "/books/" + $("#book_id").val() + "/images_list/",
      data: {
        type: "edit",
        image_width: img_width,
        image_caption: img_caption,
        image_align: img_align
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#oebImageListModal .modal-dialog").html(data);
        getUpdateSelection(current_img);
        return $("#oebImageListModal").modal("show");
      }
    });
  });
};


getUpdateSelection = function(current_img) {
  $("#cancel_insert").click(function() {
    $("#oebImageListModal").modal("hide");
    return false;
  });
  return $("#update_picture").click(function() {
    var div_style, img_align, img_caption, upd_width;
    img_caption = $("#image_caption").val();
    img_align = $("#image_align").val();
    upd_width = $("#image_width").val();
    upd_width += "%";
    if (img_align === "Middle") {
      div_style = "margin:0 auto;";
    } else if (img_align === "Left") {
      div_style = "float:left;";
    } else {
      div_style = "float:right;";
    }
    current_img.parent(".image_content").attr("style", div_style);
    current_img.parent(".image_content")[0].style.width = upd_width;
    current_img.parent(".image_content").attr("data-align", img_align);
    current_img.siblings(".caption").text(img_caption);
    return $("#oebImageListModal").modal("hide");
  });
};

return $(window).load(function() {
  loadOebPart();
  imageUpdate();
});
```

Comment: Where is the coffeescript source code?

Comment: obviously that's not the full output of the compiled coffeescript

Answer (score 1):

I suspect these are actually 2 files, and `imageUpdate` is defined in one, and called in the other.

CoffeeScript compiles into an anonymous self-executing function, the code:

```
imageUpdate = -> alert '42'
```

Compiles to:

```
(function() {
    var imageUpdate;

    imageUpdate= function() {
        alert('42');
    };
})();
```

As you can see, `imageUpdate` is local to the anonymous function, and the global scope isn't touched. This is a real advantage, because you will never accidentally clobber the global `window` scope.

You probably want to explicitly assign this function to `window`, like so:

```
window.imageUpdate = -> alert '42'
```

Alternatively, you can use the `-b` switch of the `coffee` compiler to disable this top-level function wrapper. I would *highly* recommend against this though.

Comment: Thank you so much. window.imageUpdate is working fine. Thanks a lot for your great help.

Comment: Now that error is not coming. dblclick event not getting called. Kindly help me on this.While page loads getting alert "called" but when i double click an image the event doesn't getting trigger.

Comment: @user2138489 I don't see any obvious error with the `dblclick` event, it's impossible to say anything based on just this code alone. It's also a bit of a different question, you should start a new question & copy the *coffeescript* source and relevant HTML. Set up a test page if you can.